# unable to build mainframe os development application

Tags: npm, daemon, lerna

I followed the instruction from [Mainframe OS Documentation](https://docs.mainframe.com/docs/windows) to build code my local, however, when I run

```
npm run dev
```

I am getting following error.

[image]

Comment: It would appear that this has nothing to do with mainframe computers - just some badly named PC software environment. The 'mainframe' tag should be removed.

Comment: @NicC You are right, but I couldn't find tag "mainframeos"